# Отрисовка нескольких линий Line Renderer с одной точки

Tags: unity3d

Допустим у меня на сцене есть 5 точек. Я выбираю 1, соединяю с 2. Потом хочу соединить 1 с 3, но тогда линия рисуется со 2. Создавать много Line Renderer явно не хочется. Пробовал после отрисовки линии стравить стартовую точку, но тогда вторая линия начинает баговаться. Что посоветуете?

Comment: Наверное все же зависит от того, какой сложности будут линии. Потому что если они будут что-то наподобие того, как рисуются `Debug.DrawLine` или `Debug.Ray` - то можно обойтись без `Line Renderer`. А если какой-то узорчик-рисунок - то это другое дело... Так что тут зависит...А что плохого в нескольких объектах со своим `LineRenderer`?

Comment: Линии будут прямыми между точками. По поводу дополнительных LineRenderer, то у меня будет от 5 до 10 точек и будет странно цеплять на каждой больше 5 LineRenderer.

Comment: `будет странно цеплять на каждой больше 5 LineRenderer` - странно, но когда на сцене есть например 10 врагов, у них свой компонент висит, а не один на все ;-)  .........`Линии будут прямыми между точками` - а дизайн? в таком случае можно просто инстанциировать несколько кубов (если надо, то сплющенных) с нужным материалом и нужной длиной или даже банально генерировать текстуру (какой-нибудь jpg квадрат NxN) и вытягивать по длине.

Comment: На счет дизайна - это будет линия одного цвета. Куб не подходит, так как это 2д проект и я рисую линию за пальцем. Спасибо за помощь, попробую реализовать через DrawLine.

Comment: Не уверен что DrawLine отлично подходит для рисования пальцем. Имхо, раз уж это планируется рисоваться человеком, то лучше не заморачиваться и всё-таки делать через `LineRenderer` и `Instantiate` префабов.

Comment: Ну вместо кубиков инстацируй Sprite или Quad

Comment: Вот и интересно как именно с LineRenderer это реализовать

Comment: с LineRenderer только отдельными префабами. с одной точки им по-другому никак

Comment: DrawLine не подойдет, это функция для отладки, линия не будет видна в скомпилированном проекте. Попробуйте, просто, добавлять повторяющиеся точки в массив LineRenderer'a (т.е. [1, 2, 1, 3]). Тогда линия будет рисоваться поверх уже нарисованной линии, но визуально будет казаться так как Вам нужно. Не до конца уверен что сработает, но проверить сейчас не могу. Если до завтра не отпишитесь о результате, то с утра проверю и напишу уже как ответ:)

Comment: Уже пробовал так, но когда новая линия находится рядом со старой, то она искажается, и выглядит не очень.

Comment: Тогда другой вариант: при первом рисовании массив будет [1, 2], а при втором, добавляйте точку спереди массива: [3, 1, 2]. Если нужно рисование в реальном времени (т.е. протяжкой а не по кликам), то можно обойтись двумя компонентами LineRenderer (один для рисования в реальном времени, другой для уже нарисованной линии)

Comment: Не совсем понял как это будет работать, но попробую, спасибо.